# Dynamic page URLs in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have following router config:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
  RouterModule.forChild([
   { path: 'office', component: OfficePage},
   { path: 'office/:category1/', component: OfficeInnerPage},
   { path: 'office/:category1/:category2', component: OfficeInnerPage},
   { path: 'office/:category1/:category2/:category3', component: OfficeInnerPage},
   { path: 'office/:category1/:id', component: DetailPage}
  ])
 ],
})
```

`OfficeInerPage` - List of items Controller

`DetailPage` - Detail item Controller

`:id` example *os10198*

URL examples

http://example.com/office/business_center/subway/

http://example.com/office/business_center/subway/arbat

http://example.com/office/business_center/os10198

**Problem**

Angular router state `:category1/:category2/` rewrites `:category1/:id` state. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

Somewhere in router ([source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/config.ts#L346)). I found property `matcher`, it is a `Function` which allows you handle route by yourself.

In my case I write following function:

```
function pathMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) {

  if (segments.length > 2) {

    if(segments[2].path.match(/([\w|]+[\d]+)/)) {

      let posParams = {'id': segments[2]};

      return {consumed: segments, posParams: posParams};

    } else {
    return null;
    }
  } else {
   return null;
  }

}
```

And my router config:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: 'office', component: OfficePage},
      {path: 'office/:category1', component: OfficeInnerPage},
      {path: 'office/:category1/:category2/:category3', component: OfficeInnerPage},
      {path: 'office/:category1/:category2/:category3/:category4', component: OfficeInnerPage},
      {matcher: <any>pathMatcher, component: DetailPage}, // <- here is matcher, also its conflicts with path property
      {path: 'office/:category1/:category2', component: OfficeInnerPage}, // it should be below state with matcher
    ])
 ],
})
```

Now I resolve correct these types of links:

http://example.com/office/business_center/subway/
  http://example.com/office/business_center/os10198

P.S. Useful [gist](https://gist.github.com/matanshukry/22fae5dba9c307baf0f364a9c9f7c115)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an extra path name, for instance:

```
{path: 'office/:category1/item/:id', component: DetailPage}
```

Otherwise angular has no way of knowing whether you want to go to `:category2` or `:id`, and because you have `:id` as the last thing in your array, it will overrule the first one

Comment: Yes, thank you, it is a good solution, but I have SEO requirements. So I can't do that.

Comment: I dont get how your SEO might be in trouble following this kind of standarts.